# Div on top of annotated time line

Tags: css, html, visualization, annotatedtimeline

Annotated time line is a google visualization library written in flash.  I would like to place a div on top of it at times to cover it.  However, when I do this, the div covers everything but the annotated time line shows through.  What is the problem and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Use your firebug/f12 dev tools/element inspector to mess with your elements in real time and figure it out.

Comment: not super useful comment.  I obviously tried that.

Comment: I'm sorry to be so unhelpful but this question is lacking code for us to see what the problem is. Barring that the best suggestion that I can give is to help you find tools that allow you to figure this out for yourself. Is it a zindex issue? An opacity issue? A positioning issue? Can you set the visualization's display to none? Can you move it off the screen? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with flash on the [annotated timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline). Set wmode ([window mode](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=flash%20wmode%20window%20mode&btnG=Google%20Search)) to transparent (think oqaque works to) on annotated time line

```
        annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(
          document.getElementById('timespan_chart'));

    annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {wmode: 'transparent', ...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding z-index to your div css?

```
#flashcontainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#topdiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```